# Trouble continuing loop when exception caught

Tags: java, exception, while-loop

I'm trying to continue prompting the user for a valid payrate if an invalid rate (meaning including a letter) is supplied. The problem is that if I enter a letter instead of a number then I get the `"Payrate must be > 0"` message endlessly; however, if I enter 0 or a negative number I'm prompted as expected.

What am I doing wrong and how would I fix this?

```
while (payrate <= 0) {
    try {
        System.out.print("Enter payrate: "); //ask for payrate
        payrate = input.nextFloat();  //store input from console
    } catch (Exception InputMismatchException) {
        System.out.println("Payrate must be > 0.");
        payrate = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider that `nextFloat()` doesn't consume the character(s) it tries to read if they do not form a `float`.

Comment: Also are you just trying to catch `InputMismatchException`s? If so, the syntax there is wrong.

Comment: I want to be able to catch invalid numbers and characters.  The likelihood that a character will be entered for payrate is low; however, I want to be able to handle it if it happens and not just die.

What is incorrect about the syntax?

Comment: That `catch` statement catches `Exception`, and `InputMismatchException` is the variable name. If you're trying to catch `InputMismatchException`, you want `catch (InputMismatchException ime)`, where `ime` is the variable name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `Scanner` class does not clear the input if an exception occurs, so it keeps feeding itself with a letter, if one was typed.

Also, the `payrate` variable does not need to be used for loop control.

Given the above, a simple alternative is:

```
String value;

while (true) { // Repeat until a valid payrate is entered
    try {
        System.out.print("Enter payrate: "); // Ask for payrate

        value = input.nextLine();            // Get payrate as string
        payrate = Float.parseFloat(value);   // Convert the string to float

        if (payrate > 0) { // Valid payrate number (> 0), done
            break;
        } else {           // Invalid payrate number (<= 0), repeat
            System.out.println("Payrate must be > 0.");
        }
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) { // Payrate not a number, repeat
        System.out.println("Payrate must be a number.");
    }
}
```

Comment: I've just realized that `Scanner` will not discard the value if an exception occurs.  My problem is well understood now.  Thank you for the workaround.  I'm also going to try `BufferedReader` as suggested by Sotirios.

Comment: Sure. I also don't prefer the Scanner class, but usually answer as close to the original question as possible. :-)

Comment: your workaround worked great.  I plan on playing around with `BufferredReader` as well.  Everyones help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Great! May I also add, as a general remark, that in addition to selecting the preferred answer (thanks for that :-) to all the questions (preferred and others) that you find useful. At least to the BufferedReader one, who at the moment only has my +1. Good luck with the rest of your coding.

Comment: I tried to upvote, but I'm not at 15 respect yet.  However, I will honor your request when able as I was already planning on doing it.  Thanks again!

Comment: Don't worry too much about it. Keep going! :-)

Answer (score 4):

You could use `input.next()` in your exception, since `.nextFloat()` is not clearing the invalid value.

Comment: The problem is that I need to use the payrate later on for calculations.  Eclipse is showing errors when I try and change it to String and later attempt to use is in a calculation.

Comment: @jr0207 What Patrick is getting at is what Sotirios was getting at in the comments, if there's an InputMismatchException and you try to read again, you're just rereading the same invalid value. You need a way to advance past it.

Comment: @DennisMeng 
I guess I thought that if the input were invalid that it would be discarded and a new value evaluated from command line.  If I use `BufferedReader` as @ashokramcse shows I should be able to evaluate the input before actually assigning the value to the `payrate` variable?

I will try this.  Thanks very much for the help guys.  I'll deliver the result.

Answer (score 2):

Use BufferReader insted of Scanner.

```
BufferedReader bufferRead = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

Float s = Float.parseFloat(bufferRead.readLine());
```

So u wont get that pain point...

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis I'm looking at the difference between `Scanner` and `BufferedReader` and I'm not sure I understand why `BufferedReader` would be better for my situation.  Could you elaborate please?

Comment: @jr0207 It wouldn't. `Scanner` has its own `nextLine()` method. I think the point of this answer is to use `Float.parseFloat` rather than `nextFloat()`.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
while (payrate <= 0) {
    try {
        System.out.print("Enter payrate: "); //ask for payrate
        payrate = Float.parseFLoat(input.next()); //Converts string to float
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {  //I changed the exception catched
        System.out.println("Invalid number! Payrate must be > 0.");
        payrate = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: A NumberFormatException is thrown in case the string can't be converted to a float.

Answer (score 1):

you know nextFloat() is accept or scan the next float value,  These method is throw the exception InputMissmatchException when you are not translated to a valid float value,and when you try to enter string or character you are not identify the entered value is float or not,

Remember when you declared the float variable and assign any float value you must to write "f" end to the value.
try with 10.10f

Answer (score 1):

To stay close to what's already been done, as the exception is caught the invalid contents we can clear the Scanner of the wrong input. `input.nextLine()` would read the invalid input. Not doing anything with the caught value would ignore it.

**Solution:**
Just add `input.nextLine();` in your catch block

```
           try {
                System.out.print("Enter payrate: "); //ask for payratea
                payrate = input.nextFloat();  //store input from console
            } catch (Exception InputMismatchException) {
                System.out.println("Payrate must be > 0.");
                payrate = 0;
                input.nextLine();
            }
```